# How to Change prior probabilities for predicted variable in neural networks and other methods in SPSS Statistics

Tags: probability, spss, prior

i am trying to find right model for predicting categorical variable with two values. Problem is that ratio of cases in group 1 and group 2 is not equal but rather in ratio of 2:1. When i try to find a right model then a lot of methods, mainly neural network methods always predict 99% into first group. Only methods that do not do that are discriminant and decision trees after i setup prior probabilities in these methods. Is there a way to somehow edit my dataset or force other methods to use user-defined prior probabilities? or some other way that would enable me to use neural networks or binomal regression without getting all cases predicted into first group. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, most predictive procedures in SPSS don't allow setting of prior probabilities, but LOGISTIC REGRESSION (Binary Logistic Regression) in the menus allows you to specify the cut point, which by default is .5. You can change that to accomplish something similar.